# How to determine which UIAlertView called the delegate.

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode

In the alertView delegate, theres a method:

```
-(void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex;
```

My question is, how can I find which AlertView called this delegate.

For example, I have a couple alert views which all use the delegate, but depending on which alertview called this method, I want to set up different actions for buttonIndex's.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The "alertView" object that is being passed into the method is the actual alert that is being used in the method. The most straightforward way is to provide logic inside this method that looks at the alertView object (maybe looking at the name or tag? It's up to you), and then provides different actions for each.

```
-(void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
{
  if (alertView.tag == 1)
  {
    // do something
  }
  else if (alertView.tag == 2)
  {
    // do something else
  }

  // continue for each alertView

}
```

Comment: +1 Good answer, but you should check out my post.  I much prefer using a block callback than doing conditional checking on the alert's tag.

Answer (score 4):

In all of my projects I have a class called EasyAlertView.  You can find similar code on the web, but the jist is you end up with an api like:

```
typedef void (^AlertBlock)(NSUInteger);

/** A less-unwieldly specialization of UIAlertView that allows a Block to be used as the dismissal handler. 
    This is more flexible and compact than the delegate based approach. It allows all the logic to
    be centralized within the launching method and eliminates confusion and object lifetime issues that arise
    when using multiple alerts in the same class bound to a single delegate. */
@interface EasyAlertView : UIAlertView <UIAlertViewDelegate>
{
    AlertBlock _block;
}

+ (id)showWithTitle:(NSString *)title 
            message:(NSString *)message 
         usingBlock:(void (^)(NSUInteger))block 
  cancelButtonTitle:(NSString *)cancelButtonTitle 
  otherButtonTitles:(NSString *)otherButtonTitles, ... NS_REQUIRES_NIL_TERMINATION;

@end
```

This is nice because you can write code like:

```
...
[EasyAlertView showWithTitle:@"Stuff happened"
                     message:@"All kinds of stuff just got flung around...  stop the flinging?"
                  usingBlock:^(NSUInteger buttonIndex) {
                     if (buttonIndex == 0) {  // user cancelled via "No" button
                     }
                     else if (buttonIndex == 1) { // user clicked "Yes"
                        // TODO: whatever cool logic you want here
                     }
                  }
           cancelButtonTitle:@"No"
           otherButtonTitles:@"Yes", nil];
...
```

This is nice since:

1. You can handle the action where you also define the prompt
2. Absolutely no question whatsoever as to what UIAlertView prompted this.  (not checking against the UIAlertView title or tag, which are both typical approaches).

Please note that the action handler can call into another function to handle the behavior if you want, but the point is, it is very easy to associate behavior with the prompt.  Before we used this code, we had some mazes of if / else statements in the UIAlertView protocol `- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex` implementation that checked against tags / titles of UIAlertViews.  :(  Was no bueno.

Here is the EasyAlertView implementation:

```
#import "EasyAlertView.h"

@implementation EasyAlertView

- (void) dealloc
{
    [_block release], _block = nil;
    [super dealloc];
}

+ (id)showWithTitle:(NSString *)title message:(NSString *)message usingBlock:(void (^)(NSUInteger))block cancelButtonTitle:(NSString *)cancelButtonTitle otherButtonTitles:(NSString *)otherButtonTitles, ...
{
    EasyAlertView * alert = [[[EasyAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:title
                                                         message:message
                                                        delegate:nil
                                               cancelButtonTitle:cancelButtonTitle
                                               otherButtonTitles:nil] autorelease];

    alert.delegate = alert;
    alert->_block = [block copy];

    va_list args;
    va_start(args, otherButtonTitles);
    for (NSString *buttonTitle = otherButtonTitles; buttonTitle != nil; buttonTitle = va_arg(args, NSString*))
    {
        [alert addButtonWithTitle:buttonTitle];
    }
    va_end(args);

    [alert show];

    return alert;
}

- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
{
    if (_block)
    {
        _block(buttonIndex);
    }
}

@end
```

Also see [An enhancement for UIAlertView](http://blog.roguesheep.com/2010/02/19/an-enhancement-for-uialertview/)

Comment: I'm aware that other similar implementations use selectors rather than specifying a block as I have done.  I prefer the block syntax, but even the selector syntax is better than the out-of-the-box UIAlertView delegate pattern for the simple reason that it is common to have multiple different alerts under a single UIViewController (or other logic handling class).

Comment: Good to know, i'll try it, the logic seems very useful for other UI elements too.

Answer (score 3):

Use [tag](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIView_Class/UIView/UIView.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIView/tag) property

Comment: +1 how it's usually done.  If you want to see another way that I feel is superior, check out my post.

Answer (score 3):

I realize this is kind of late, but came across this while looking for a solution to my own similar issue. I resolved this by assigning my different alerts as properties.

This example assumes ARC and iOS 5, but should work as a good example. Hope this helps.

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) UIAlertView *passwordAlert;
@property (nonatomic, strong) UIAlertView *warningAlert;

passwordAlert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Password" message:@"Enter password" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel" otherButtonTitles:@"Done", nil];
passwordAlert.alertViewStyle = UIAlertViewStyleSecureTextInput;
[passwordAlert show];

-(void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex {
   if (alertView == passwordAlert) {
      // handle anything for password button indexes here
   }
   if (alertView == warningAlert)_ {
      // handle anything for warning button indexes here
   }
}
```

Comment: This one is on point. Best solution by far. Purple monkey dishwasher

Answer (score 2):

Set a `tag` to each alert you want to trigger, `alterView.tag=10;` for example, then in the body of the method you posted check the alert:

```
if(alertView.tag==10){
   //your alert
}
```

Comment: +1 helpful answer.  You should check out my post on this as I offer a very different approach.